# Plugin Development: Disable Content Assist at specific contexts

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How can I disable my content assist plugin for specific contexts? Ex: I've done a extension of `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.completionProposal` for .ftl files, but I want to disable the extension at some circumstances (Ex: only woking in specific type of projets). I thought that I could use the Activator class for that, but it doesnt look like.